# Massive param binding in PHP/MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, mysqli, prepared-statement

**Hello all,**

I know for a fact the below looks stupid(and funny, too), but this is what I've used to do back in the mysql days (one giant query with all the variables stuck in), I am not sure if this is even the right way to do it in mysqli, but certainly I am doing something wrong here because this block ***does not*** execute

```
if($query_rows == 0){
                $pass_hash = hash("sha512", $reg_pass);
                if($prep_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, user_type, 
                first_name, last_name, gender, expr_rating, user_rank, rank_type, user_expr, user_legion,
                num_hosted, num_attended, email, premium_status, premium_credits, location_city, 
                user_sex_interest) VALUES (?, ?, 0, ?, ?,
                ?, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, ?, 0, 0, 'waterloo', ?)"))                    
                    { 
                        // Oh my gawd -.-
                        $prep_stmt->bind_param("ssssisi", $reg_user, $pass_hash, $reg_fname, $reg_lname,
                        $reg_gender, $reg_email, $reg_sexint);

                        $prep_stmt->execute();

                        $err = $mysqli->error;
                        echo($err);
                        echo($mysqli->error);

                    } else {
                        if(DEVMODE){ // devmode is enabled
                            $err = $mysqli->error;
                            echo($err);        
                            echo($mysqli->error);                        
                            echo("derp"); exit();
                        } else {
                            $stop = true; header("Location : error.php?id=99");
                        }
                    }        
                }
```

:P Help a noobie here! Thanks all!

Comment: MySQLi will take care of quoting the variables for you. You don't need `'?'`, only `?`.

Comment: Still doesn't work x) I tried the query in MySQL workbench and it worked fine, swapping the ? with actual values. Could be be that mysqli doesn't know what I am trying to bind? I mean with $query rows I did it once with bind_param("ss", $var1, $var2) which both are strings

Comment: If `$mysqli->prepare()` fails, look at what [`$mysqli->error`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) reports.

Comment: It doesn't print anything x) lol it jumps straight to the else block

Comment: Step through this code under a debugger, such as [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). See which parts of the code are actually executed.

Comment: I finally know why... MYSQLI cannot prepare the statment... thats why it jumped the boat so fast -.- but then... I don't know *why* can't it prepare it :P to me it looks legit

Comment: okay after renaming the variables I get "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command nowCommands out of sync; you can't run this command now" :(

Answer (score 0):

**SOOO MUCH DERP :D**

This solves it all

```
$prep_stmt->close();
```

Then do whatever its needed

Bye world :D